# No text in the InfoWindows of Google Maps API from array

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am building this Google Map from their API, but I cannot write text in the InfoWindow. How do I write the name of each country using a the jsonp array shown in the code? My aim is being capable to be able to add any indicator from any other array into the InfoWindow.

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(25, 25),
    });
    var url_countries = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all?format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata&per_page=304';
    var query_url_countries = url_countries;
    console.log(query_url_countries);

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = query_url_countries;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

window.Getdata = function(data) {
    var country_data = data[1].map(function(item) {
        return {
            country: item.name,
            longitude: item.longitude,
            latitude: item.latitude,
        }
    });
    console.log(country_data)
    for (i = 0; i < country_data.length; i++) {
        var country_display_data = country_data[i];
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(country_display_data.latitude, country_display_data.longitude);
        var contentString = country_display_data.country[i];
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(this.contentString);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
          map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues with your code:

1. a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) doesn't have a `contentString` property.  You can add a custom contentString property by setting it in the constructor, in the [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions))
2. `country_display_data.country` is a string, so `var contentString = country_display_data.country[i];` is a single letter.

```
var contentString = country_display_data.country;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latLng,
  map: map,
  contentString: contentString
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mta8vtuo/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25, 25),
  });
  var url_countries = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all?format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata&per_page=304';
  var query_url_countries = url_countries;
  console.log(query_url_countries);

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = query_url_countries;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

window.Getdata = function(data) {
  var country_data = data[1].map(function(item) {
    return {
      country: item.name,
      longitude: item.longitude,
      latitude: item.latitude,
    }
  });
  console.log(country_data)
  for (i = 0; i < country_data.length; i++) {
    var country_display_data = country_data[i];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(country_display_data.latitude, country_display_data.longitude);
    var contentString = country_display_data.country;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      contentString: contentString
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(this.contentString);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
      map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.